# OSx Mavericks Python-LDAP pip install failing

Tags: python, macos

I have found a few references to OSX Python-LDAP install issues but none of them relate to the errors Im getting.

Below is a snippet of the install output. As you can imagine if I try to `import ldap` I get the following;

**Import error**

```
Python 2.7.8 (default, Jul  2 2014, 10:14:46) 
[GCC 4.2.1 Compatible Apple LLVM 5.1 (clang-503.0.40)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import ldap
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: No module named ldap
>>>
```

**Install Error**

```
sudo pip install python-ldap
Downloading/unpacking python-ldap
Downloading python-ldap-2.4.16.tar.gz (137kB): 137kB downloaded
Running setup.py (path:/private/tmp/pip_build_root/python-ldap/setup.py) egg_info for package python-ldap
defines: HAVE_SASL HAVE_TLS HAVE_LIBLDAP_R
extra_compile_args:
extra_objects:
include_dirs: /opt/openldap/include /usr/include/sasl /usr/include
library_dirs: /opt/openldap/lib64 /usr/lib
libs: ldap_r

file Lib/ldap.py (for module ldap) not found
file Lib/ldap/controls.py (for module ldap.controls) not found
file Lib/ldap/extop.py (for module ldap.extop) not found
file Lib/ldap/schema.py (for module ldap.schema) not found
warning: no files found matching 'Makefile'
warning: no files found matching 'Modules/LICENSE'
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): setuptools in /opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages (from python-ldap)
Installing collected packages: python-ldap
Running setup.py install for python-ldap
defines: HAVE_SASL HAVE_TLS HAVE_LIBLDAP_R
extra_compile_args:
extra_objects:
include_dirs: /opt/openldap/include /usr/include/sasl /usr/include
library_dirs: /opt/openldap/lib64 /usr/lib
libs: ldap_r
file Lib/ldap.py (for module ldap) not found
file Lib/ldap/controls.py (for module ldap.controls) not found
file Lib/ldap/extop.py (for module ldap.extop) not found
file Lib/ldap/schema.py (for module ldap.schema) not found
..................<SNIP>
```

Comment: I don't think StackOverflow is the right forum for this question. I suggest you take it to the package maintainer.

Comment: @MichaelWarner apologies on the delayed response. I dont think this is a package problem. It seems to be MAC related. I tested it on another systems (windows) and it works fine.